# How to sum the values of nested dictionary

Tags: python

I have the following Python code

```py
dict_projectdirector = {
    "Project director": {
        "Name": "John",
        "Age": 28,
        "Experience": ["A", "B", "C"],
        "Hours in project": 3500
    }
}

dict_staff = {
    "Name": "Helene",
    "Age": 20,
    "Experiencie": ["D", "E"],
    "Hours in project": 500
},
{
    "Name": "Helene",
    "Age": 31,
    "Experience": ["A", "C", "F"],
    "Hours in project": 1100
}

print("\nPeople assigned to the project:")
Project_staff = {
    "Project director": {
        "Name": "John",
        "Age": 28,
        "Experiencie": ["D", "E"],
        "Hours in project": 3500
    },
    "Basic staff": dict_staff
}

print(Project_staff, "\n")

hours_project_director = (Project_staff["Project director"]["Hours in project"])
print("Project director hours:", hours_project_director, "\n")
```

I wish to sum the `"Hours in project"` from the `dict_staff`. I am trying
to iterate, but it does not work. Could you help me?

Thanks Oscar

Comment: The code you pasted is the input data to be parsed. Please also paste the solution that you say does not work. As stated in https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.". Also paste the current output of your algorithm. We wouldn't know what you need to correct if we haven't seen your solution in the first place. Unless you really want us to solve it fully for you?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, your declaration of `dict_staff` is wrong, make it a list:

```
    dict_staff = [{
    "Name": "Helene",
    "Age": 20,
    "Experiencie": ["D", "E"],
    "Hours in project": 500},
    {
        "Name": "Helene",
        "Age": 31,
        "Experience": ["A", "C", "F"],
        "Hours in project": 1100}]
```

With that you can simply loop over it:

```
sum_hours = 0
for member in dict_staff:
    sum_hours = sum_hours + member["Hours in project"]

print(sum_hours)
```

Output:
`1600`